# How to answer a question which is similar to another question

Tags: discussion, answers

Suppose a user asks a question and another similar question is present on SO, but with a little bit of difference in words. And someone else gives it an answer by following answers to similar questions, and also puts the reference from where he got the answers.
Is it wrong to answer the question in this way?
If it is wrong then what should to do with that question?

Comment: I think you should flag it as possible duplicate.

Comment: but if the user is new then how he will get the answer of his question?

Comment: When you flag it as duplicate, the link to other question is posted in comments(the question for which you are flagging it as duplicate) and it'll have the answer. If you are wrong somebody from community will correct you in comments and eventually the OP has many chances of getting the answer.

Comment: what is the benifit of mark as duplicate the question will be available on the SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### If the question is a duplicate of an existing question…

Vote/flag to close the new question as a duplicate of the existing question.

A duplicate question is one that, although it is asked in a slightly different way, has *exactly the same answer* as the original question.

This is preferable to answering the duplicate question a second time because it keeps all the information consolidated in a single place, where it can be more easily found, vetted by the community, and kept up-to-date. You or anyone else can always post a new answer to the original question if you have something to contribute. Or, you can edit one of the existing answers if a trivial fix is needed.

The person who asked the duplicate question also benefits directly because they get their answer immediately. All they have to do is follow the link to the master question that appears once their question has been marked as a duplicate.

It is worth noting that there are three ways to mark a question as a duplicate, depending on the privileges you have earned on the site:

- [Under 3,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), you will have to *flag* the question as a duplicate. Do this by clicking the "flag" link underneath the question, selecting the "it is a duplicate" option, and pasting the link to the original question. Your suggestion will be put into a queue to be reviewed by more experienced users. If enough of them agree, the question will be marked as a duplicate.
- [At 3,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you have sufficient privileges to cast close/duplicate votes of your own. It works the same way as flagging, except that you click the "close" link that appears underneath the question. Your vote will be counted as one of the 5 required votes.
- If you hold a gold badge for one of the question's original tags, you have [insta-duplicate-marking privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). The logic is that you're an expert on the subject/topic of the question, and you are the best judge of whether or not it is a duplicate. You've also been hanging around that tag for long enough to know what has already been asked.

#### If the question is *not* a duplicate of an existing question, but merely *similar*…

It should not be closed as a duplicate. As mentioned above, duplicates are those with exactly the same answer. If the new question covers similar ground, but has a slightly different answer, then it is not a duplicate.

These questions should be answered. If you can answer them, do so!

However, if they are similar to other questions on the same topic that you think the information might be of value, you should include a link to the other question in the body of your answer for reference purposes.

If you borrow heavily from another person's answer, adapting it to the different circumstances of the new question, you *must* give credit to the person who originally posted the answer. Do this by mentioning their user name and linking to their answer in the body of your post.

Comment: agreed with your answer beacuse i was confuse about it now its clear