# Answering a Question with other Answers/Posts

Tags: discussion, answers

*Sorry if this was asked before, I tried searching for a similar post in regards to this matter but did not find anything.*

I am trying to start helping contribute back to StackOverflow by answering easier questions within the css/html/java/javascript tag range. A common issue with this, is that most "easy" questions are quite similar and have been asked and answered already many times.

I have two questions on this, and I understand that a good chunk of these "posts" will get marked **duplicate** eventually, but sometimes this takes awhile (or does not happen at all) so in the meantime.....

1. If the user's question has been sufficiently answered on another (or multiple) StackOverflow posts, should we:

   **-** Leave a comment with the other post's answer and leave it at that?

   **-** Submit an actual answer, but that still relates back to the other post?

   I see pros/cons to both, with a simple pro being that more threads means more keywords for users to hopefully hit on an initial search, but I see a con to this also being either wasted or clustered space.
2. If it is constructive to leave an actual answer for future searches, should we just post a link or actually replicate the code within the answer from the other post? All of this obviously including a: brief but helpful explanation, additional details related to the question, and a references with "credit given" to the other post's answer author.

Again, I see pro's and con's to both as different keywords will hit different posts, and with more posts having an actual answer we can help more users without any effort, but I also see the con in doing this.

Despite being a young coder, I do try my hardest to give user's a solid answer accompanied with JSFiddle demos. Most answers are of my own, but sometimes I do need to rely on other user's posts as well.

I want to help out where I can, but I want to do it correctly as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: For #1, don't put a comment pointing to another post, that's what flags are for (if it's a duplicate).

Comment: Strongly related/possibly duplicate: [How to answer a question which is similar to another question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260740)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do neither.  You should flag (or vote to close) the post as a duplicate.  The comment linking to that post will be auto-generated by the act of flagging (along with much stronger additional benefits, such as a banner).

Comment: Even if the question itself is not truly a duplicate? Many times people have different specifics or minor detail adjustments.

Comment: @Austin You're claiming in the question that you feel that just linking to the other question seems sufficient to you, so clearly the answers to that question answer this question, and any differences are not germane to the answer.  Duplicates aren't just for copy-paste questions after all.

Comment: Okay, I shall just mark anything I come across as duplicate then. I just feel bad sometimes because it may only answer 95% of their question. :/ Thank you for the input!

Comment: @Austin Often times you can explain the remaining 5% in a comment.  E.g., "This is a duplicate of X.  In your case, it's just that Y turns into Z' instead of Z."  You can edit the automatically-generated comment, so you can even put it there, but the comment may get deleted when the question gets closed as a duplicate, so it may be better to put it in a separate comment.